# Use of options/switches with "set" command

Tags: tcl

I have come across a script (a section of it is shown below) which uses switches/options with `set` and `proc` in Tcl. Need help with the use and purpose of using the following constructs i.e switches and options with `set` and `proc` ...

```
set opt_args {
    -login_user        ANY
                       DEFAULT lab
    -login_passwd      ANY
                       DEFAULT lab 
}

set man_args {
    -ti           ANY
    -ra_name      ANY
    -r_name       ANY
}

aetest::script_init -mandatory_args $man_args \
        -optional_args $opt_args  -return_direct \
        -common_section_id last_test_id
```

Comment: It's just a string literal.

Comment: This is specific to Cisco. You have better luck searching the intranet or asking around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `script_init` expects some string literals as arguments. You'll need to consult the documentation for that function to know how they are interpreted. Most likely it's a little DSL (domain specific language) for defining mandatory and optional arguments.

The things that might look like options to the set command aren't -- it's all just data.